# Are Azure Functions a good fit for splitting up big processing jobs?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-functions

I have a big batch of processing, running via C# code and ultimately deployed to the Azure cloud, which I want to speed up. The processing involves a large amount of data. There are four collections of data, all of which are related to each other, and are often in size as follows:

- 10 items
- 100 items
- 10,000 items
- 1,000,000 items

The processing basically has to loop through the largest collection, and search for a corresponding record in each of the other collections, and then increment a count. In theory, the task at hand is simple, but there are ***lots*** of look ups within the collections, which is where nearly all of the time is spent. On my development machine, the process can take 1-2 hours when the collections reach this size. The machine has 32 GB RAM and an Intel i7 3.4 GHz CPU with 4 dual cores and it only hits about 20% CPU utilization during execution.

I need to speed this up to 2 minutes (or worst case 5 minutes). Given the nature of the data,  splitting up the work amongst multiple "workers" is easy in concept and should support a gain in speed. My plan is to split up the largest collection into a few smaller chunks and create a few threads so that the existing hardware can be more fully utilized to achieve a faster result. I expect that this will succeed in reducing the processing time, but I highly doubt it will be enough. So I'm investigating splitting that largest collection even more, and having multiple machines each take a chunk of that work (with each of them threading as well).

**Considerations**:

The need for this processing is intermittent and unscheduled. It generally needs to happen during the day, and it might need to happen every couple of hours, every few days, or maybe only once a month. So these are some important considerations:

1. It can't be cost prohibitive, so I can't have tons of dedicated VMs running 24x7 waiting to process. This is compounded by the fact that the end solution has to be implemented in 3 separate data centers.
2. While its cost prohobitive to have dedicated VMs running all the time, I don't have much time to wait for infrastructure to spin up on demand because I really need to get the results within 2 minutes and my experience with Azure is that new resources spin up reasonably quick, but not seconds-quick.

These considerations make me think of Azure Functions.

**My Questions**:

1. **Are Azure Functions a good fit for splitting up this processing?**
2. The infrastructure behind Azure Functions is abstracted (purposefully), **so do you know if the hardware has multiple cores to fully support multi-threading?**
3. **Are there other alternatives in Azure that seem like a better fit for this?**

Comment: Just out of curiosity where is the bulk of the work occurring if it is not CPU bound? Are you doing a lot of disc I/O like DB or network calls during the processing? I can't imagine something as trivial as 1 million iterations of a loop taking hours to run...

Comment: @JesseCarter That's the weird thing, there isn't anything going on other than the processing of the in-memory data. No disk or network. Before posting my question, I knew that I really needed to optimize my search algorithm, but I wasn't confident enough that it would be good enough so I assumed I'd still arrive here needing to look at this option. Its implemented "quick and dirty" as a proof of concept, but I can see after thinking about this more and reading the answers suggested so far, that I need to improve the search algorithm before I go down this path.

Comment: I'd be really interested to see more of the implementation I feel like this should easily be able to run on a single machine in minutes or less. We aren't talking about big datasets relatively speaking here

Comment: @JesseCarter Agreed. I built the proof of concept in a quick and dirty way just to see if I could solve a particular problem better than some other options I've explored. So for quick testing in the POC, I used the .NET Linq framework for searching, which is likely doing an inefficient linear search. It turns out that my problem is solved very well with this approach, so now its time to start caring about the finer details of the implementation and its performance. A more efficient search makes sense. (Thanks for your interest in the thread and for your comments)

Comment: Trevor would you be willing to post any info about your search code? I feel that the biggest issue here is what's happening in your loop. I've built simple multi threaded console apps that are able to process millions of items per minute on a single PC tons of times. The fact that you're still running at 20% CPU is extremely telling that something is going wrong with the core implementation. Moving to Azure Functions to try to improve is performance is not as important as fixing this.

Answer (score 3):

With all respect, 1,000,000 is not much if you just need to loop through them once with constantly low time per item. And if it fits into memory of one computer (it should easily), then it's the best way to go.

To extend @Mike's answer:

- Bring all your data in memory
- Hash the smaller collections based on the lookup key
- Iterate though the biggest collection and do lookups per item

Hash lookup is constant time, so you get an algorithm which has `O(n)` complexity where `n` is the size of the big collection.

If you try to distribute the load, you might get the same complexity but multiplied by the time of network call for each item, which is way slower than local RAM access.

If you ever reach the size beyond single server's RAM, go split the biggest collection into chunks and bring all the remaining hash tables to each server to keep the lookups local.

Azure Functions are for event-driven scenarios, not really for data crunching.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the majority of your time is spent reading in the 1 million items. 
You can use Azure Functions to easily host your code in the cloud in an elastic fashion (not paying 24-7).
If you have some form of parallelism here (ideally splitting up that million), you can queue a message for each slice and let Azure functions run them in parallel.  You're probably IO bound (pulling down the million rows), not CPU bound.

Another idea is to find some compressed way to store that million so that you can quickly ingress it. IE, have a background task (timer?) that scans through it and writes the hashes to a N large blobs that you can quickly read in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hashing algorithm.  Hashing 10,110 items and then checking for the 1000000 in that set.